Dynamically replace column names with values of that column
I have a pyspark dataframe that is like this:



A1
A2
A3
Cols
is_column




4
6
2
A1
1


5
1
3
A3
1


1
3
4
22
0



I would like to replace the A1 and A3 with their respective value when is_column = 1 else keep the cols value. how can i achieve that?



A1
A2
A3
Cols
is_column




4
6
2
4
1


5
1
3
3
1


1
3
4
22
0




you could use func.when to check the column name that matches the value in cols column.
here's an example
from functools import reduce

# columns to match
col_list = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']

# use reduce to dynamically create func.when statement for all columns
when_statement = reduce(lambda a, b: a.when(func.lower('cols') == b.lower(), func.col(b)), col_list, func)
# generated statement
# Column<'CASE WHEN (lower(cols) = a1) THEN a1 WHEN (lower(cols) = a2) THEN a2 WHEN (lower(cols) = a3) THEN a3 END'>

# usage
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('cols_out',
               func.when(func.col('is_col') == 1,
                         when_statement.
                         otherwise(func.col('cols'))
                         ).
               otherwise(func.col('cols'))
               ). \
    show()

# +---+---+---+----+------+--------+
# | a1| a2| a3|cols|is_col|cols_out|
# +---+---+---+----+------+--------+
# |  4|  6|  2|  A1|     1|       4|
# |  5|  1|  3|  A3|     1|       3|
# |  1|  3|  4|  22|     0|      22|
# +---+---+---+----+------+--------+

essentially, we are checking if the value within cols column is matching with one of the columns in the list. once matched, we will use the value in func.col() to fetch the value from that column.
e.g.,
func.when(func.lower('cols') == 'a1', func.col('a1'))
#                                ^^             ^^


I figured out with reduce or expr my codes did not work because they all made "case when" statements for columns that do not appear in cols.

You can create a map to handle the replacement, see below:
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

cols = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']

result_df = df.withColumn('m', F.map_from_arrays(F.lit(cols),F.array(cols))) \
    .withColumn('Cols_new', F.expr("if(is_column=1, m[`Cols`], `Cols`)"))

result_df.show(3,0)
+---+---+---+----+---------+---------------------------+--------+
|A1 |A2 |A3 |Cols|is_column|m                          |Cols_new|
+---+---+---+----+---------+---------------------------+--------+
|4  |6  |2  |A1  |1        |{A1 -> 4, A2 -> 6, A3 -> 2}|4       |
|5  |1  |3  |A3  |1        |{A1 -> 5, A2 -> 1, A3 -> 3}|3       |
|1  |3  |4  |22  |0        |{A1 -> 1, A2 -> 3, A3 -> 4}|22      |
+---+---+---+----+---------+---------------------------+--------+

Spark before 3.4.0 F.lit() does not support array, you can change F.lit(cols) to  F.array(*map(F.lit, cols)) or use F.create_map() function to create Map.
